# RedDot with Lotus Notes support

Tags: java, lotus-notes, reddot

First post here in SO.
I have a question within the area of CMS (RedDot) and possible integration of some Lotus Notes functionality. I'm very fresh in both areas.

From my short research (did not find very much material regarding RedDot) I got the following:
Contents in RedDot CMS can be accessed (and modified?) via the RQL API. (basicly xml messages)
There exists a API developed for Java (jRQL). 
Lotus Notes has a developer kit called Lotus Expeditor Toolkit.

My vague question is something like this:
Is it possible to integrate a some kind of "content approver/manager" or any other useful CMS functionality from Lotus Notes into the RedDot CMS system?

In that case I was thinking of using the jRQL and Lotus Expediton Toolkit so that the back end is fully using Java.
Or is there any better solution?

Regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedrik,
check carefully. Is jRQL a rest based XML service (basically URLs you can get/post XML) or a SOAP based XML service (one URL and a soap wrapper). In the later case you can just use a web service client, in the first case you would write a Java agent (a java class expanding a certain interface).
What would make sense is to have a composite application in Lotus Notes (you use the free Domino Designer for that) that retrieves the list of entries in Reddot to be approved. It would show a list of them and in a panel the actual site in a browser when you click on the list item. The list (in Notes lingo: view) can have approve/reject/revise this buttons which would a) document the decision in Notes b) send an XML to Reddot to approve/reject this.
You could go even further :-)
The web container in Lotus Notes would allow you to submit web forms dynamically using code, so you could get away with the XML stuff.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for the response. That will do for now. Is it possible to develop Lotus Notes applications in .Net as well? I just found another open API that wrappes the RQL in .NET.

Comment: don't bother. Notes runs on Windows, Mac, Linux (Client). Windows, Linux, AIX, Solaris, zOS (Server). So you want to stick a solution that can run there too - Java